# CentOS 7 shell_exec and exec always null

Tags: php, shell-exec

I am currently creating a webhook script for my gitlab repo. This script will run some shell command like git to clone the repository. I run the shell command like this

```php
$output = shell_exec('which git');
var_dump($output);// NULL
```

But there is no output and git is installed when I run `which git` directly in bash on my server.

My server is amazon ec2 instance centos 7 with cpanel and whm installed.

I already check if it is disabled on php ini on whm but its not.

What could be the reason why shell_exec not outputting anything

EDIT:

Same with

```php
exec('which git', $output);
var_dump($output); // NULL
```

Even if I added `2>&1` to the command to ouput it on `stderr` and `stdout`.

Comment: Does the user the webhook runs under have git? If you do `shell_exec("whoami");` is it the user you expect

Comment: @chiliNUT that is the problem when I run that command no output also so I couldn't identify the user.

Comment: If you ran `which git` for a user that did not have git installed, the expected result would be `null`. When you ran `whoami` it also returned `null`?

Answer (score 0):

try [exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php):

```
$output = exec('which git');
print_r($output);
```

EDIT:
I found that on some OS shell_exec is not working, however when shell_exec is not working, I simply use exec(). It could be because the newer version of PHP had something to do with this because in the past shell_exec() function was used for malicious purposes.

Comment: Hello thanks for your reply I already tested in on my server both `exec` and `shell_exec` returns null. Even if I added `2>&1` to the command to ouput it on `stderr` and `stdout`.